# Access and Trunk Port

Tags: cisco, trunk

I have an access port that I'm trying to change to a trunk port.  So, while I'm on the interface I
want to change and do:

```
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan x
```

a `show run` command then gives

```
interface GigabitEthernetx/x
switchport access vlan xx
switchport trunk allowed vlan xx
switchport mode trunk
```

Is this port now a access port and a trunk port at the same time?  If so, how do I fix it so that the port is only a trunk port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is correct. Changing the modes does not remove all of the configuration that the port previously had, in case you need to switch back for any reason.  So, whatever it says in the `switchport mode` line is what the port’s operational mode will be (access or trunk).  The portion that still references the access VLAN will be ignored and is effectively there for historical purposes.